# IF statement when update a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `Products` with this content:

```
  | Product title | price | price_sales | new_price |
1 | Product A     | 100   | 80          | ???       |
2 | Product B     | 100   | 0           | ???       |
3 | Product C     | 400   | 200         | ???       |
```

I have to do an update query about all products: the column `new_price` has to be a column with **10% discount** on the current price. 
When there is no price_sales (price_sales = 0), the column `price` is the actual price.

The result has to be:

```
  | Product title | price | price_sales | new_price |
1 | Product A     | 100   | 80          | 76        |
2 | Product B     | 100   | 0           | 90        |
3 | Product C     | 400   | 200         | 180       |
```

Comment: UPDATE Products SET new_price =  (price * 10.0 / 100.0)

Comment: When there is a price_sales (price_sales > 0), the new price is 10% discount of price_sales. When there is NO price_sales (price_sales = 0), the new_price is 10% discount of price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
update tbl 
set new_price = if(price_sales > 0, price_sales * 0.9, price * 0.9)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exacly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
update tbl set new_price = if(price_sales > 0, price_sales, price) * 0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE Products SET new_price = if(price_sales > 0, (price * 10.0 / 100.0), price)
```